# Add region constraint to Graphics

Tags: graphics

I would like to only show the part of `Black` circles within the `Red` circle.

Can I do that with `Graphics`, `Circle` and/or some sort of **Region Constraint**?

[image: the upper half]

```
step = 2 Degree;
\[Alpha] = Range[2 Degree, 80 Degree, step];
x = ConstantArray[0, Length@\[Alpha]];
y = Sec@\[Alpha];
radius = Tan@\[Alpha];
range = 1.01;
Graphics[{Red, Circle[{0, 0}, 1], Black, 
  MapThread[Circle[{#1, #2}, #3] &, {x, y, radius}]}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-range, range}, {-range, range}}]
```

At the moment, I use `ContourPlot` with `RegionFunction` option. However, my plot contains a large number of these circles (The amount of the circles shown here is only a quarter for the current `step`), which makes `ContourPlot` approach very slow. Moreover, when I zoom in, quite often I find the *circles* drawn by `ContourPlot` are not circular, presumably due to `PlotPoints` and `MaxRecursion` etc. I tried to play with these two options, but did not succeed in terms of quality (being a circle) and speed.

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the three-argument form of `Circle`:

```
Graphics[{Red, Circle[{0, 0}, 1], Black, 
    MapThread[Circle[{#1, #2}, #3, {π + ArcTan[#3], 2 π - ArcTan[#3]}] &, 
     {x, y, radius}]}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-range, range}, {-range, range}}]
```

[image]

Alternatively, use `RegionIntersection` with `Disk[]` to get the needed portions of black circles:

```
circles = MapThread[Circle[{#1, #2}, #3] &, {x, y, radius}];

circles2 = RegionIntersection[Disk[], #] & /@ N[circles];

Graphics[{Red, Circle[{0, 0}, 1], Black,  circles2}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-range, range}, {-range, range}}]
```

> same picture

**Update:** An alternative way to *hide* unwanted portions of `circles` using [`FilledCurve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FilledCurve.html):

```
filledCurve = FilledCurve[{{Line[Append[#, First @ #]& @ 
   CirclePoints[range Sqrt @2, 4]]}, 
  {Line[Append[#, First @ #]& @ CirclePoints[200]]}}];

Graphics[{Red, Circle[{0, 0}, 1], Black,  circles, 
  EdgeForm[None], White, filledCurve}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-range, range}, {-range, range}}]
```

> same picture as above

Comment: I used the 1st method of yours, which is the fastest among all the provided answers at the moment. But it seems the `ArcTan[#3 Sqrt[1/(1 + #3^2)] Sqrt[1 + #3^2]]` can be shortened to `ArcTan[#3]`. Also, the center of the circles lies along the y axis, which is a special case. I wonder what this method could be if the center of the circle is arbitrary. Could you please elaborate if possible? Thanks. I realized that for the "arbitrary center" case, it requires the actual information of the circle, and therefore, it maybe changes from case to case.

Comment: @Bemtevi77,  updated with the simpler form. Re arbitrary centers, I think the second and third methods should work as is. I think the first method should also work but I am not sure.

Answer (score 5):

```
g = Graphics[{Red, Circle[{0, 0}, 1], Black, 
   MapThread[Circle[{#1, #2}, #3] &, {x, y, radius}]}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-range, range}, {-range, range}}];

Show[g, RegionPlot[x^2 + y^2 > 1, {x, -1.2, 1.2}, {y, -1.2, 1.2}, 
  PlotStyle -> White]]
```

[image]

Comment: I realized that this method can be easily applied to "circles with arbitrary center and radius" as asked in my comment to kglr's answer. It may not be the fastest, but is more versatile, in my opinion. Thank you very much!